# How to Override edit button's method in smart templates sapui5

Tags: sapui5

[image]

This is the object page of the list report page of the smart templates.
I want to override the method of the edit button in the controller extension of my application.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to answer without assuming how the application was built. I'm assuming that you utilized SAP Build to build this. If so, then from the Page Editor it is possible to click on the "Edit" button, then scroll down to the actions on the Properties sidebar to see which events are implemented.

If implemented, they will be in a Controller file with the same name (eg. S2_**.controller.js) and you can do a search for the event handler (eg. onClick in case of Edit).

In any case, no matter how the application was built - you can check each controller file for it's outline (in Web IDE) and search for the appropriate handler to override.